# Pattern/validation making a dot between numbers in input

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

As the title says I'm trying to make input like 4.11 so when user inputs 4 automatically hes thrown to last two numbers and there is dot between them so. I'm using jquery validation i tried patterns but I have just no idea how to do something like that at all.
**EDIT**: That's pretty much all I have I have no idea how to approach something like that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#first_form').validate({
            rules: {
                patch: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 4,
                    remote: {
                        url: "checkpatch.php",
                        type: "post"
                        }
                    }
                },
            messages: {
                patch: {
                    required: "Please enter patch version.",
                    remote: "Patch with this number already exists."
                    }

                }
        });
    });
```

Comment: "thrown to last two numbers"? Huh?

Comment: All i'm tring to do is make user put 3 number which are actually the number of patch so 4.16 but the user will not have to put the dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jquery plugin which is very handy for your goal... it is called maskedinput (https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)... Check it out!

I have also prepared a basic demo setup based on your demand: number(dot)number-number (ie 4.82):

html:

```
<input type="text" name="num" id="num">
<button id="clr">Clear</button>
```

javascript:

```
//masked input definitions
$.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
$.mask.definitions['x'] = '[0-9]';
$.mask.definitions['*'] = '[-A-Za-z0-9._\\\/?&=~]';

$("#num").focus();

$("#num").mask("x.xx", {
    placeholder: ""
});
$("#clr").on("click", function () {
    $("#num").val("");
    $("#num").focus();
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/captain_theo/u91q7p4h/

For more info, I suggest you go through the documentation of the plugin...

Happy Holidays!